# php $_GET value couldn't pass to mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Before I posted this question, I already search in SO and Google and on top of that I also use [mod_rewrite generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php).

However the result i put it in my .htaccess it seems not to be working.

my current url:
`http://localhost/jeff/test/result.php?start=2-1-2014&end=2-1-2014&submit=Go`

my desired output:
`http://localhost/start/2-1-2014/end/2-1-2014`

The code I got from mod_rewrite  generator:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/jeff/test/result\.php\?start=([^&]+)&end=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /start/%1/end/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^start/([^/]+)/end/([^/]+)/?$ /jeff/test/result.php?start=$1&end=$2&submit=Go [L,QSA]
```

Now each time I press the submit button, it still return me back to the old url instead of rewrite the url as per .htaccess

**Side Note:**

- My XAMPP already uncomment the mod_rewrite engine
- I already tested the mod_rewrite module with other project and it's working
- I tried to restart apache a few time but yet I couldn't get the result

Where did I go wrong? I believe the generator give me the correct result.

Here is my submit form code:

```
<form method="get" action="result.php">
From: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
End: <input type="text" name="end" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

and my result.php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// bind column to variable
//Connect to DB
$host = "localhost"; //Host Name
$port = '3306'; //Default MySQL Port
$dbname = "mama"; //Database Name
$db_username = "root"; //MySQL Username
$db_password = ""; //MySQL Password

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
  $start_date = $_GET['start'];
  $end_date = $_GET['end'];
  $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start_date);
  $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end_date);
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= :start AND log_datetime < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY");
  $success = $query->execute(array(':start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'), ':end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d')));

}
// Catch any exception thrown
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  // Exit, redirect, whatever you need to do.
}
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Screenshot of my current setting:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

No `RewriteBase` is wrong and won't work for you.

Put this code in your **`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/jeff/test/result\.php\?start=([^&]+)&end=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /start/%1/end/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^start/([^/]+)/end/([^/]+)/?$ /jeff/test/result.php?start=$1&end=$2&submit=Go [L,QSA]
```

Comment: not working as well, i tried to put on `htdocs` folder not working, i put it in `htdocs\jeff` not working and I put it into `htdocs\jeff\test` folder also not working.

Comment: It needs to be in `DocumentRoot` and you have to make sure there is no other .htaccess in `/jeff/` OR `/jeff/test/`

Comment: `DocumentRoot` means `htadocs` ? I'm using XAMPP, can you be more specific on the `DocumentRoot` besides that, I already remove all `htaccess` in all folder

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is standard Apache terminology and is defined in your `httpd.conf` file. It might be `htdpcs` OR some other directory that only you can check. Alternatively you can create a `phpinfo.php` file with `<?php
phpinfo();
?>` content and see it in your browser to get this info.

Comment: `_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"] C:/xampp/htdocs` as per phpinfo and I put it in exactly the same place

Comment: I just retested this rule again and it is working fine. Make sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled and working and this is **first** rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: please refer my screenshot at my first post, everything is did as per the answer but yet to get me the correct format

Comment: Are you entering: `http://localhost/jeff/test/result.php?start=2-1-2014&end=2-1-2014&submit=Go` in your browser?

Comment: sorry to say, but it's not working as well :( my form is `method="get"` and the result.php contain `$var=$_GET['start'];

Comment: not working as well, anyway I updated with my form and result.php code, is it possible my code give all the error even the mod_rewrite is correct?

Comment: Yes very much possible that code is doing something that you haven't shown in your question yet. Rules are working perfectly fine in all my testing. What is the final URL you see in your browser (after form submit)?

Comment: before submit the form `http://localhost/jeff/test/form.html` and after submit the form result `http://localhost/jeff/test/result.php?start=2-1-2014&end=2-1-2014`

Comment: Ok that URL should redirect to `http://localhost/start/2-1-2014/end/2-1-2014` (as it is doing for me). Do you have other rules in your .htaccess also? OR just just recheck if there is any other .htaccess left anywhere?

Comment: just checked, everything remove. as well I tried using my online host at here `http://jeff.omgmobile.my/form.html`it seems when I submit the url doesn't rewrite as well.

Comment: Ok can you place your latest .htaccess in your question? Are you sure mod_rewrte and .htaccess are enabled?

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: [Server Error](http://jeff.omgmobile.my/form.html) tested as your suggest and it return me the error

Comment: ok .htaccess is enabled. Now add a this rule: `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]` in same .htaccess and then try to open `http://localhost/foo`